# What does "$\binom n k$" mean?

Tags: notation, binomial-coefficients

\begin{align}
& \binom n 0 + \binom n 1 + \binom n 2 + \cdots + \binom n n = \\[8pt]
& \text{(A)}\,\,\, 2^{n-1} \qquad \text{(B)} \,\,\, {}^{2n}C_n \qquad \text{(C)} \,\,\,2^n \qquad \text{(D)}\,\,\,2^{n+1}
\end{align}

Why is there nothing inside the bracket (between the $n$ and the number)?

Comment: Because the ${n \choose k}= {}^nC_k = C(n,k) $ is the notation for binomial coefficients.

Comment: You may want to learn how to use MathJax; that's what we use to make our equations etc come out nicely. See here for an excellent guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: *Why is there nothing inside the bracket (between the $n$ and the number)?* How the Hell did you know the binomial coefficients tag applied?

Comment: @Shaun OP originally posted this as an image of what looks like an exercise sheet; that had in quite big font the words "Properties of Binomial Coefficients"

Answer (score 3):

Simply,

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The numbers inside the brackets *don't* represent fractions. They are known as binomial coefficients and that is how we write them. For example,
$$\binom{3}{2}=\frac{3!}{2!1!}$$

Very simply, the binomial coefficent $\binom{n}{k}$ (pronounced $n$ choose $k$) represents the number combinations that can be formed from $k$ items out of $n$ items.

Comment: For more details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @HarshDarji you're welcome! I hope we've helped you :) Are you familiar with binomial coefficients?

Answer (score 2):

$${n \choose k}$$ means "for a set of size $n$, how many subsets have size $k$" ?  For example, the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$ of size 4 has 6 subsets of size 2: $\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, d\}, \{b, c\}, \{b, d\}, \{c, d\}$
, so
$${4 \choose 2} = 6$$

> $$\begin{align}
> & \binom n 0 + \binom n 1 + \binom n 2 + \cdots + \binom n n = \\[8pt]
> & \text{(A)}\,\,\, 2^{n-1} \qquad \text{(B)} \,\,\, {}^{2n}C_n \qquad \text{(C)} \,\,\,2^n \qquad \text{(D)}\,\,\,2^{n+1}
> \end{align}$$

This is asking "how many subsets of size 0 plus subsets of size 1 plus...." which can become the question "how many subsets are there (from a set of size n)?"

Comment: Thank you so much!